# Checkbox - Method or data member not found

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently facing an issue "METHOD OR DATA MEMBER NOT FOUND" whenever i click anywhere in my Excel file.

It directs me to below checkbox1.

[image]

After all, I press "OK" and it highlights the query highlighted in yellow.
[image]

The very weird case is that this error only pops up in 1 of the PC.

I tried running the same excel file on other PC and it went well.

Additional info for Tools > Reference as shown below:

[image]

And also the Object(Checkbox and CommandButton) is not showing in Dropdown list.

[image]

Can anyone help on it?? Appreciate!!

Comment: You don't have Checkbox1 on sheet1.

Comment: @cyboashu Checkbox1 already inside the Excel page. Just that the particular PC not able to run the VBA.

Comment: What happens if you try `Me.CheckBox1`?

Comment: Also, what's the excel version on that pc?

Comment: @sktneer i tried changed to Me.CheckBox1 but the error still prompt. Excel version 2013.

Comment: When you type `Sheet1.CheckBox1`, does the `intellisense` show the `CheckBox1` in the list? Also are you sure that it is an `ActiveX CheckBox`?

Comment: So the problem, from my point of view, is, that you are referring to the object `Sheet1`. I'm not quite sure, what it's supposed to do, but try using the generic sheet object with the corresponding index, e.g. `Sheets(1).CheckBox1.Value = True`.

Comment: Is the MSCOMCTL.OCX registered on that PC?

Comment: @sktneer The intellisense not showing checkbox1.

Comment: @prextor Not sure how it work. I tried changing Sheets(1).CheckBox1.Value = True but error still appear.

Comment: @AcsErno Registered but still same..

Comment: Ok, same question as @sktneer: does intellisense shoes Checkbox1 if you are typing `Sheets(1).Che`?

Comment: No, it not showing @prextor

Comment: As i have mentioned, only 1 of the PC having such issue while the rest got no issue. I have tried the excel file in 2007, 2010 no problem. When it comes to Excel 2013, it show the error above.

Comment: Which error still appears? Still "Method or Data Member not found" ?
Otherwise make sure, that the Design Mode under Developer -> Controls is turned off.

Comment: Yes, "Method or Data Member not found" error still occurring. The developer mode is off.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the `available references` in your `VB project`? To do so, open `VBA Editor` --> `Tools` --> `References` --> Take the screenshot of the opened window and share it.

Comment: Hi @sktneer, i've added the info.

Comment: Can you close all the files and `open a new workbook` and place an `ActiveX CommandButton` on Sheet1 and then place a simple code like `MsgBox "OK"` underneath it and see if the message box pops up when you click the `CommandButton`? This will ensure that the `ActiveX Controls` are being supported by the `Application`.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks @sktneer for guiding me to ActiveX. The problem occur cause by the ActiveX. By installing the link below help to solve the issue.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3025036/-cannot-insert-object-error-in-an-activex-custom-office-solution-after

Comment: You're welcome Sunny! Glad your issue has been resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok at the top of the of a module's code pane, there are two drop-downs.  The left one will usually contain something like `(General)` for an ordinary module or `Worksheet` for a sheet module.

Assuming you are in the Sheet1 module, can you see if `Checkbox1` is available in that left drop-down?

I've had some strangeness with this.  If you need to resort to some code then this gets an ActiveX control checkbox with code

```
Friend Function ActiveXCheckBox() As MSForms.CheckBox
    '* use this if you inserted a ActiveX Checkbox
    Dim myActiveXCheckbox As OLEObject
    Set myActiveXCheckbox = Me.OLEObjects.Item("CheckBox1")

    Dim chk As MSForms.CheckBox
    Set chk = myActiveXCheckbox.Object

    Set ActiveXCheckBox = chk

End Function
```

Dropping an ActiveX control on the sheet should add a property automatically, one can usually see it in the object browser for the workbook.  Your code is relying upon it.

Comment: CheckBox1 is not available in the drop-down menu for both "General" & "Worksheet".

Comment: Add code given above and see if it finds the checkbox, please.  That is copy in the code and press F5, it will complain if CheckBox1 really does not exist.

Comment: After added and press F5, it show run-time error '1004': "Unable to get the Object property of the OLEObject class".

Comment: on which line please?  `Set chk = myActiveXCheckbox.Object` ?

Comment: sounds very very strange.  I'd re-register the controls dll with regsvr32.  Also I'd rebuild a brand new workbook to see if something has become corrupted along the way.

Comment: Yes, this line "Set chk = myActiveXCheckbox.Object". Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas, I'm afraid.  That it works on some machines and other not implies some mismatch in dlls somewhere.  So you have to re-register some dlls I think.